# Finding correlation between numeric encoded categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics

So I have a data set which has categorical variables. I have encoded each category from 0:x depending on the amount of categories x. I am trying to find the correlation between the variables (both numeric and categorical) to the target variable (which is also categorical, but has been coded to 0 for no and 1 for yes).

I have been able to run this code for the correlation(s) for all the variables (there are about 17) and it does seem to work, but I question whether the correlations are correct. I haven't calculated the correlation with categorical variables in my data set before, just want to ensure that I am going about this the right way:

```
print(df['previous'].corr(df['y']))
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The trick to finding correlations within categorical variables is to dummify them. While your target variable is fine (since it i binary), the categorical variables having multiple classes need to be dummified -

```
pd.get_dummies(df['Categorical_Column'])
```

Once done, delete one column from the dummified columns and then get the correlations...

Comment: I am actually running an SVM algorithm on my data set, and I have manually recoded all my categorical variables based on their categories. Did I go about this wrong? Additionally, can you possible elaborate as to what these dummified variables contain? And would I do the correlation between these dummified variables and my target variable y?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html for get_dummies docs and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics) wiki link for understanding dummy vars

Comment: Thank you. So would these dummy variables work with multi-class features? One of my categorical variables is the days of the week. So once I create these dummy variables column, I run the statistics for this dummy variables column and the target variable y?

Comment: yes you can. Just make sure you dont fall into the "dummy variable trap". Remove one column from the output dummy columns so that you ensure there is no singularity in the dataset

Comment: Okay I think I am understanding you. So I thought of creating a new dataframe containing only the dummy categorical variables and the other numeric variables and I am planning on running my SVM on this. Would this be the way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Correlation analogue for categorical data is called cross tabulation (you get a contingency table for your data). You can do it in pandas using [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So looking at crosstab, I would set the columns to equal all of my categorical variables and it does this encoding for me?